# noun form of phrase means "after hours"

Tags: phrase-request, nouns

I think the phrase *after hours* is adverb, so it cannot be used in the sentence below as it needs a noun.

What's the suitable noun?

> The closing time of childcare centers is usually earlier than after hours of companies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't really anything convenient. But even if there were, this is a very roundabout way of saying

> Childcare centers usually close earlier than (most) companies.

I'm guessing that what you mean is

> Childcare centers usually close before parents can leave work.